# How to compare difference in dates without changing from datetime

Tags: python, pandas

Thanks for your time and consideration. Here's my df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date 1': ['3/10/2020', '3/11/2020', '3/12/2020'],
                   'Date 2': ['3/14/2020', '1/11/2021', '6/03/2020']})
df['Date 1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 1'])
df['Date 2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date 2'])
df['Date Diff'] = abs(df['Date 1'] - df['Date 2'])
df
```

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to keep everything as the same datetime, but it makes it hard to do stuff with it. What I would like to do is create a flag if it's past a certain date difference. I tried to use a loc function, but it didn't work.

```
df["Over 90 Days"] = ""
df['Over 90 Days'].loc[df['Date Diff'] > 90] = True
df['Over 90 Days'].loc[df['Date Diff'] <= 90] = False
df

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidComparison                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)
   1007         try:
-> 1008             other = self._validate_comparison_value(other)
   1009         except InvalidComparison:

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py in _validate_comparison_value(self, other)
    545         elif not is_list_like(other):
--> 546             raise InvalidComparison(other)
    547 

InvalidComparison: 90

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-006d0523989e> in <module>
      1 df["Over 90 Days"] = ""
----> 2 df['Over 90 Days'].loc[df['Date Diff'] > 90] = True
      3 df['Over 90 Days'].loc[df['Date Diff'] <= 90] = False
      4 df

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     68 
---> 69         return method(self, other)
     70 
     71     return new_method

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py in __gt__(self, other)
     46     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__gt__")
     47     def __gt__(self, other):
---> 48         return self._cmp_method(other, operator.gt)
     49 
     50     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__ge__")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)
   5500 
   5501         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 5502             res_values = ops.comparison_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
   5503 
   5504         return self._construct_result(res_values, name=res_name)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py in comparison_op(left, right, op)
    268     ):
    269         # Call the method on lvalues
--> 270         res_values = op(lvalues, rvalues)
    271 
    272     elif is_scalar(rvalues) and isna(rvalues):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py in new_method(self, other)
     67         other = item_from_zerodim(other)
     68 
---> 69         return method(self, other)
     70 
     71     return new_method

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py in __gt__(self, other)
     46     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__gt__")
     47     def __gt__(self, other):
---> 48         return self._cmp_method(other, operator.gt)
     49 
     50     @unpack_zerodim_and_defer("__ge__")

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimelike.py in _cmp_method(self, other, op)
   1008             other = self._validate_comparison_value(other)
   1009         except InvalidComparison:
-> 1010             return invalid_comparison(self, other, op)
   1011 
   1012         dtype = getattr(other, "dtype", None)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\invalid.py in invalid_comparison(left, right, op)
     32     else:
     33         typ = type(right).__name__
---> 34         raise TypeError(f"Invalid comparison between dtype={left.dtype} and {typ}")
     35     return res_values
     36 

TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int
```

I even tried looking into trying to swap it back to an actual number and remove the "days" that come inherently with the datetime but it didn't work for me. Help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pd.Timedelta`:

```
df['Over 90 Days'] = df['Date Diff'].gt(pd.Timedelta(90, 'd'))
```

Output:

```
    Date 1      Date 2      Date Diff   Over 90 Days
0   2020-03-10  2020-03-14  4 days      False
1   2020-03-11  2021-01-11  306 days    True
2   2020-03-12  2020-06-03  83 days     False
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks! Out of curiosity, what does the 'd' in the second argument refer to? I couldn't find anything in the docs.

Comment: "d" or "days" or "day" are all possible inputs here for days. The first example in the [`pd.Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) docs uses `"d"`. Or you could use `pd.Timedelta(days=90)`, if that's clearer, as demonstrated in the second example.

Comment: Thanks! I know you've already been a big help but if I wanted to flip things around and go for under 90 days, how would I adjust this?

Comment: Change `gt` (greater than) to `lt` (less than).